# How to handle only landscape orientation on my app?

Tags: ios, ipad, tablet

I am building an app mainly for tablet or iPad, but I just noticed that the design is meant to only for landscape view. I tried the portrait and it doesn't look good. Though before I keep programming the app I want to know how I can handle this, or prevent the user to see the app in portrait.

I checked and I know that for android I can use something like this: 
    android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"

but what about iPad?
I would like to have something more "universal" if I can say

I am using HTML5, JQuery and to handle the swipes I am using Hammerjs nothing else, I didn't use any mobile framework, cause it's more of a carousel with some text and images.

Comment: on iOS it's a simple configuration in the App Target, where you just allow Landscape Left and Landscape Right

Answer (score 1):

on iOS it's a simple configuration in the Xcode App Target, where you just allow Landscape Left and Landscape Right.

if you are using UIKit for building the app, you can configure it for every instance of UIViewController

**UPDATE: (Solution for HTML)**

combine the css rule "*transform: rotate(90deg)*" with css media queries on device orientation, but it will be tricky to get everthing to run properly....

Comment: is there anything in CSS or JS that I could use? I am simply using HTML5 and JQuery since it't a carousel with some text and images, so I didn't find it useful to use a framework for this

Comment: you want to block the safari browser from going to portrait ? that's not possible.

Comment: but you could hide your app with css media queries on the device orientation. and show another div saying "this webpage only works in landscape"

Comment: maybe not block it from going on portrait but show it landscape 90 degrees even if it's on landscape

Comment: you could combine the css rule "transform: rotate(90deg)" combined with css media queries on device orientation, but it will be tricky to get everthing to run properly....

Comment: Thanx! I've been working on this for 2 days, and I am about to finish it. As soon as I finish I can post it as an answer for other people who had the same question

Comment: yeap! has to be done for today! don't want to spend xmas working